# ChartJs Get date from dropdown and then refresh Charts

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a dashboard right now that produces graphs and data from the database based on the current year. I am trying to add a dropdownlist of years and then have the graphs in the dashboard change on the year select. I have 2 areas that have to change and I am having issues with getting the variable for the year in the URL. I dont want to post the whole script because it is lengthy. My dropdown works fine, I just cannot use the variable in the string.

This is how it is currently setup:
Inside a  `$(document).ready(function () { }`

```
    SalesByMonth()

    var Year = new Date().getFullYear()

    $('#year').change(function () {
        Year = document.getElementById("year").value;
        $("#year").val(" ");
        console.log(Year);
    });

    function SalesByMonth() {
        var Year = new Date().getFullYear()
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetChartData", "Dashboard", new { Year = "Year" })',
```

The variable "Year" is not seen by the function. Even if I put it in the function `SalesByMonth`

Answer (score 0):

After doing some searching I figured out what works.
First in my CHTML page I had to put this:

```
@{ var dates = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString(); }
```

Because I could not get the JavaScript `getFullYear()` to work at all. It was always null. No matter how I tried to do it. Then I got my variable like this with the select function right below it:

```
   var currentYear = @dates;

    $('#year').change(function () {
        currentYear = document.getElementById("year").value;
        $("#year").val(" ");
        console.log(currentYear);
        SalesByMonth();
        Revenue();
    });
```

Here is my selectlist:

```
<div class="form-group sol-container">
   @Html.DropDownList("Year", null, new { @class = "sol-container-selection", id = "year" })
</div>
```

Then in my ajax url I had to do this:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetChartData", "Dashboard", new { Year = "year" })'.replace('year', currentYear),
```

The call to `SalesByMonth` and `Revenue` functions in the `.change` function refreshes the charts with the current year.

And just to complete this to have the full code, here is my controller for the dropdown list.

```
 AccountingEntities acct = new AccountingEntities();
 var list = acct.Transaction.Select(s => s.TransactionDate.Year).Distinct().OrderByDescending(s => s).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString() });
 ViewBag.Year = list.Select(x => new SelectListItem
                                 {
                                    Value = x.Text,
                                    Text = x.Text
                                 }).ToList();
```